# Handle connection error with libCurl

Tags: c++, curl

I'm using libCurl in multi-threaded way (curl_multi_perform), but don't know how to implement things so that I could handle the case of losing network connection (or any HTTP error).
looks it never invoke my callback when there is any network issue. though in verbose mode I saw the following logs:

```
…. * getaddressinfo (3) failed.
    * Couldn't resolve host xxxx
```

and I've set up things as :

```
           …...
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, actual_url);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, 1);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, callback);
          ……

              CURLMcode cm = curl_multi_add_handle(multi_handle, curl);
    cm = curl_multi_perform(multi_handle, &request_handle_count);

    printf("CURL_MULTI_PERFORM: %d\n", cm);
```

and nothing comes in the `"callback"` function in a network failure :(

Answer (score 0):

CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION is used to retrieve response data. On a network failure there will be no data. So callback will not be called. To recognize network failover you have to use return code of curl_multi_perform. You can make your own callback function and call it when return code (cm) not equal to CURLM_OK. To gain callback feature you can save function pointer and then call it.

```
char ErrorStr[200];
```

//this function will be called

```
void OnError(CURLMcode errorCode, char* Error)
{

}
```

//In your code

```
CURLMcode res;
do{
    res =  curl_multi_perform(curlm, &count);

}while(res == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);

if(res != CURLM_OK)
{
  slprintf(ErrorStr, 200, "curl_multi_perform() failed: %s\n",
          curl_multi_strerror(res));
    OnError(res, ErrorStr);

}
```